# cant get req object in post fetch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

Code of the node.js program:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../client/' ,'build')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors());
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body); //always empty
})
```

I think the node.js program is right but every time front-end application hits the url `req.body` is always empty and I don't know why.

My front-end application is built with React.js and below is the code where I call the `fetch()`.

```
fetch('/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        task: details
    }),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
```

Comment: have you tried sending a request from POSTMAN to verify your server ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing couple things:

In your frontend:

```
fetch('/', { 
method: 'POST', 
body: { task: details },
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
 })
```

In your server side:

```
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{ 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); //always empty 
})
```

This should works.